# Loading String Array To Chrome Extension With Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Working on a chrome extension that requires reading from a list of constant string data (a lot of it). In any other context, I'd want to store this in a text file and read each line in at the start of the program.

However, there seems to be no good way to do that using Javascript for this extension. The soltuions I've been able to find use XMLHttpRequest, but there's internet protocol involved in this extension (runs entirely self-sufficiently off local files, which get compressed when the extension is finished).

So right now I'm essentially just declaring a string array at the beginning of the Javascript file that has 150 strings as of current (only going to grow as I generate more), then I access the array later on in that same file.

This looks so nasty and I have to scroll way down to get to any actual code for this to work. Is there a more elegant solution in loading up the data from a separate .js file, or is there actually a way to use XMLHttpRequest (or something else) to access a text file in the same directory as the .js file that's running?

Comment: It's unclear what prevents you from using XMLHttpRequest or `fetch`. Both can be directly used on a file inside the extension package, this is as trivial as `fetch('file.json')`. The only complication may be in case you want to use it in a content script directly: for that you need to declare the file in `web_accessible_resources` and use chrome.runtime.getURL.

Comment: @WOxxOm My lack of full understanding of web development. Fetch works like a charm. Appreciated.